# Dockerwith fastapi

Tags: python, docker, fastapi

currently I am working on a project with docker ,specially docker with FastApi, here is a simple main code :

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
return {"message": "Hello, World!"}
```

I also created a docker file and here is the code:

```
# Use Alpine-based Python image
FROM python:3.9-alpine

# Set the working directory in the container

WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app

COPY . /app

# Install dependencies

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the source code into the container.

COPY . .

# Command to run the application with automatic reload

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--reload","--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

The problem here is that it doesn't reload automatically and it returns:
"GET /wpad.dat HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
Any idea how i can solve this problem

I searched a lot but i don't know what is the true answer.

Comment: 1 - Probably not the issue but you have a "}" in end of the Dockerfile.
2 - What's in the requirements.txt?

Comment: Why should `GET /wpad.dat` return anything? You haven't defined any routes that matches your request - only a route for `/`. How are you running your container? Since you've just copied the app into your container, those file won't change if you change anything locally on your computer; they're only updated when the container gets built. Which OS are you running on? Have you mounted any local directories into your container?

Comment: 3 - Why are you copying the same things to two places in the container? Lines 3 and 6 in the Dockerfile (both Copy commands).

Comment: about the requirements.txt:
fastapi>=0.68.0,<0.69.0
uvicorn>=0.15.0,<0.16.0

Comment: Actually ,I am beginner with docker, so could you recommend a tutorial for docker with fastapi,please?

Comment: okay, first i build the image using this command :
docker  build -t image .
then after building the image i write this command:
docker run -d my container -p 80:80 image

Comment: About the OS, i run it on windows, I use docker desktop, But i really want with help of docker even i am in windows machine to build  my python code that's only run in Linux machine , Any idea How can i do that?

Comment: You could just install Python without Docker, if you think Docker is part of the issue.  The [Python 3.12.2 release](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3122/) includes Windows binaries, for example.  That would take one variable out of the problem and give you a simpler development environment.

Comment: @OlaMamdouh, you don't need a tutorial about Docker with FastAPI, you need a tutorial for each separately.

Comment: 4 - What is the route you try to access when you get the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you've went through the tutorial [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/docker/) I'll just say that if you'd copy-pasted from that it would work, or at least should work.
As it stands here are the issues I've found in your code and the changes that I made to make it work:

1. The whitespacing matters!

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"message": "Hello, World!"}
```

is not

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
return {"message": "Hello, World!"}
```

2. The Dockerfile:

```
# Use Alpine-based Python image
FROM python:3.9-alpine

# Copy the source code into the container.
COPY . .

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Command to run the application with automatic reload
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--reload","--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

Should be sufficient. If you are copying the entire directory there is no need to do it in stages.
Obviously the build has to be done after adding the `requirements.txt` file.

Then to run, run `docker run -dp 8080:80 my_contianer`. This is prefreable to running on port 80, as that is a reserved port and could cause issues.

To make sure it works look at Zombo's answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/483754/is-there-a-built-in-command-line-tool-under-windows-like-wget-curl). The short of it is that you can just open the Windows command line and type `curl.exe localhost:8080` and get the desired result.